# how to get the value of selected index of array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have array in java script i want that it may give the value of that index and show to data div in html now it is showing the index of the array not value i want value i have given the jsfiddle link

```
 <div id="data"></div>     


 and here is the script 


       var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
        var con=document.getElementById('data');
        var inds = $.map(ad, function(v, i) {
            return v == 'b' ? i : null;
        });

        alert(inds); // 0,3,
        var avr1=inds;
        con.innerHTML=avr1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Acja/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you expect 'b'? Change this line:

```
var avr1=inds;
```

To

```
var avr1=ad[inds];
```

To get the element of `ad` at index `inds` -> `ad[1] = 'b'`

**Edit:** You could get the output 'aaa' using the below, it's a bit simpler than you method, it counts the number of 'a's in the array and then makes a string based on that.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/Pescf/)

```
var con = document.getElementById('data');

var char = 'a';
var str = '';
var ad = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'a'];
var count = ad.filter(function (v) {
    return v == char;
}).length;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    str += char;

alert(str);

con.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: it is working for b but when i give a then it show undefined see this i want that when i use a it show three times a as they are three times  http://jsfiddle.net/2Acja/3/

Comment: Are you expecting 'a' to be alerted? or 'a, a, a'?

Comment: yes that is what i want it should alert a a a and also show a a a in div